# Value of Airflow variable gets invalid on restarting docker container

Tags: python, docker, airflow

There is a long list of dags and associated airflow variables at some remote instance of airflow, copy of which is running in my local system. All the variables from remote airflow instance are imported to my local airflow instance.

I have installed airflow image on top of docker and thereafter started the container. Everything works fine and I can access the airflow UI from my local system.

**Problem:**
Whenever I restart the airflow container, all the variables that were imported during the previous container run get invalid like this.
[image]

**Work Around**
Import the variables again to fix the variable related error.

However, Its really frustrating to import variables every time container starts. There must be an intelligent way of achieving this. Please help me understand what am I doing wrong.

Comment: by any chance are you using `SQLite`? If yes; make sure the SQLite storage directory is **[1]** properly mounted on your docker container **[2]** has proper permissions

Comment: Right, I can see variables  like "sql-alchemy...." in airflow config file. For instance, sql_alchemy_pool_size, sql_alchemy_pool_recycle, sql_alchemy_pool_enabled etc. Its really long file though and I am not aware of what eaxactly it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New encryption key is generated when the docker container is restarted.

To ensure that the same encryption key is used you will have to either hardcode a FERNET_KEY in the config file or pass an env variable when the container is initially run.

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8080 -v D:\dev\Dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags -e FERNET_KEY=81HqDtbqAywKSOumSha3BhWNOdQ26slT6K0YaZeZyPs= --name my_airflow_dags airflow_image
```

The Fernet key here can be anything. Once this key is provided, docker can reuse the same every time container is restarted.

Answer (score 3):

The Root Cause of this Problem is the [AirFlow Encryption Mechanism for the Key-value Variables](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/variable.html).
when you import your variables manually, their `is_encrypted` attributes, are automatically set to `True`.

Whenever, you restart the container, new **Encryption Key is generated**, thus the old ones got `Invalid`.

**You Have 3 Options :**

- Set the `fernet_key` explicitly in airflow.cfg
- [Set the `AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY` Environment Variable in docker-compose.yml](https://bcb.github.io/airflow/fernet-key)
- Set the `is_encrypted` attributes to `False`([Admin UI, CLI, update sql query , ...](https://marclamberti.com/blog/variables-with-apache-airflow/))

I personally chose the second one, so my `docker-compose.yml` file, looks like this :

```
       environment:
           - LOAD_EX=n
           - EXECUTOR=Local
           - AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY='81HqDtbqAywKSOumSha3BhWNOdQ26slT6K0YaZeZyPs='
```

thanks to [wittfabian](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/issues/549#issuecomment-624052455)